# Is there a distinction between "le rêve" and "le songe"?

Tags: choix-de-mot

Regarding the title of a recent publication from Gallimard:
Auteur: ALICIA GALLIENNE
Titre: "L’autre moitié du songe m’appartient"

Question: Are the words "le rêve" and "le songe" completely interchangeable, or is there a distinction between the two? In expressions such as "Je songeais qu'on pourrait aller au théâtre" it seems best translated as "I was thinking we could go to the theatre," indicating just a thought, not a dream.

Answer (score 15):

For many centuries, *songe* used to be the only word to mean "dream" in French. It cames from the Latin *somnium* which relates to *somnus* (*sommeil*, sleep).

Other romance languages have kept *somnium* as the main word for it (sp:*sueño*, it:*sogno*, pt:*sonho*, cat:*somni*, ro:*somn*...).

On the other hand, *rêve* was created from the verb *resver* that meant to wander, ramble or prowl. *Resver* etymology is not firmly established, there are competing theories.

Anyway, *rêve* had for a long time the negative connotation inherited from *resver*<sup>1</sup> while *songe* was the neutral and positive word for dream.

*Rêve* lost its negative side and became more popular than *songe* in the nineteenth century.

[image]

Nowadays, the substantive *songe* is almost never used in casual French so *un rêve* and *un songe* are definitely not interchangeable unless a poetic/literary effect is expected.

The verb *songer*, while rare, is still used but has shifted its meaning from *rêver* to *penser* with a small nuance. *Penser* means to think (of something) while *songer* is more like to imagine the eventuality of something, to consider something. Compare:

> *Je pense me présenter aux élections.* : Odds are high it will happen.
>
> *Je pense à me présenter aux élections.* : I do not forget to do it.
>
> *Je songe à me présenter aux élections.* : I'm still unsure and likely still weighing up the pros and cons.

We can see that in the *songer* case, there is still a part of dream in the sense imaginary images or events are showing up in your mind.

Some references:

[D’où vient le mot « rêver ? »](https://presse.signesetsens.com/psycho/dou-vient-le-mot-rever.html), Marc-Alain Descamps

[Rêver

Le mot, la chose, l'histoire](https://journals.openedition.org/terrain/3150), Daniel Fabre

<sup>1</sup><sub>*L’étymologie du mot rêver révèle essentiellement son sens dépréciatif. Rêver, c’est délirer, sortir du sillon. Celui qui rêve, divague et extravague. Le mot rêve semble en effet venir du latin vagus (vagabond, qui erre ça et là, à l’aventure), d’où le verbe esver et resver au XIIIe siècle, « errer, aller ça et là pour son plaisir ».* Marc-Alain Descamps</sub>

Comment: Dans de domaine de la mythologie, le songe est l’apparition de l’image d’un dieu, d’un ange ou d’un être spirituel qui annonce un évènement à venir, révèle quelque chose à une personne, lui donne une ‘mission’  : Le souffle [l’Esprit] d’Athéna venait le matin [en passant par le trou d’une serrure] près de l’oreille de Pénélope pour la guider dans son attente … faire un "songe creux" c’est rêvasser sur le néant == débilité ; dans ce domaine, le rêve est un concept que l’agitation mentale génère en flux continu, le songe est une image que notre conscience nous envoie … à nous de s’en saisir.

Comment: @cl-rSOrendezconfianceenFL Oui, ça va dans le sens de l'ancienne distinction *songe*, phénomène positif et *rêve*, phénomène négatif.

Comment: Alors, "Je songe d'un Noël blanc" ?

Comment: @HarryAudus Non car *songer* utilise la préposition *à*, jamais *de*. La phrase *je songe **à** un Noël blanc" est donc possible.*

Comment: Pour "je songe à e présenter aux élections" ça me semble exactement synonyme de "je réfléchis à me présenter..." mais qui serait tout de même plus probable qu'un "j'hésite à me présenter..."

Comment: @XouDo Pas exactement synonyme pour moi. *Je réfléchis à* me semble plus une démarche plus consciente et volontaire alors que *je songe à* se rapproche plus de quelque chose qui se produit en arrière plan, qui frôle l'inconscient.

Comment: What is the "negative" side of _rêve_ that you refer to?

Comment: @ruffle An old one closer to *délirer*, *divaguer*.

Comment: @jlliagre - An old what? And what is the old one?

Comment: @rufle An old meaning. If you can read French, have a look to this [document](https://presse.signesetsens.com/psycho/dou-vient-le-mot-rever.html) already referenced in my reply.

Comment: @jlliagre - Can you perhaps add a sentence to your answer to say what you mean by "negative", because as it stands that's not clear at all.

Comment: @ruffle Quote added.

Answer (score 1):

The word "songe" is essentially the literary word for "rêve" and it is not used much in everyday language to say "dream".
 In a less important way it's a word that is used with the meaning of "daydereaming" ([TLFi **C.**](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/songe), "Rêverie à laquelle on se laisse aller à l'état de veille, construction de l'imagination") and then it is usable in everyday language, but few people will use it, only the more literary minded will and at that rather in the particular context of lofty enough thougts, and instead people will have recourse to non neutral terms such as the rather pejorative "rêvasserie" (however, the verb "rêvasser" is more common ([ref.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=r%C3%AAvasserie%2Cr%C3%AAvasser%2Cr%C3%AAvass%C3%A9%2Cr%C3%AAvassait%2Cr%C3%AAvasse%2Cr%C3%AAvassant&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cr%C3%AAvasserie%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cr%C3%AAvasser%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cr%C3%AAvass%C3%A9%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cr%C3%AAvassait%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cr%C3%AAvasse%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cr%C3%AAvassant%3B%2Cc0)); the particular meaning of "rêvasserie" [TLFi, **B.**](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/r%C3%AAvasserie) corresponds to the following meaning of "rêvasser": "([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/r%C3%AAvasser), Laisser la pensée, l'imagination se perdre en des rêveries vagues, changeantes et souvent chimériques. Synon. rêver (v. ce mot I B)".

There does not exist a substantive with the root of "songer" and a corresponding meaning when "songer" means, as you say, "thinking". The meaning is that of [TLFi, **II.B.1.a)**](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/songer), "penser réfléchir".
To be perfectly correct, it is not absolutely true that there does not exist a corresponding substantive ; there is one, "songement", and we find it under the pen of a certain Barbusse ([TLFi, **Rem.**](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/songer): "Songement, subst. masc.,rare. Fait de songer, rêverie. Te v'là en songement, toi, camarade, qu'est-ce que tu songes? (Barbusse,Feu, 1916, p. 106)"). The writer is therefore entirely free to  adhere to this coining, it is up to the reader to find out what the word means;  of course, the writer must not mind  the eventuality that this usage might make them appear somewhat odd, unconventional.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104978/discussion-between-cl-r-so-rendez-confiance-en-fl-and-jlliagre).

Answer (score 1):

The preceding answers give a good point of view of the distinction between "*rêve*" and "*songe*" in literature.

But more precisely, on a psychological point of view, there is a real distinction between "*rêve*" and "*songe*" in modern French:

"*rêve*" means a dream made during your sleep: everybody dreams every night, though we don't always remember our dreams.

"*songe*" means something different: a "*songe*" is a dream made while you don't sleep, that's why we talk about "*l'air songeur*", having the same meaning as "*l' air absent*": your body is there, but it seems your mind is somewhere else: in that sense, we use "*songe*" for "*rêverie*", which is a kind of false dream, that you construct intellectually after your desire. This is the light sense of "*songe*".

But the real "*songe*" is exactly like a dream: you mentally see images and hear dialogues that show a story and totally captivate your attention, as strongly as in a dream at night, but though you're awake you don't chose what you see, it comes by itself, independently of your will, just as if you were watching a movie. In fact, real "*songes*" are quite rare, and most people don't have a single one in their whole life.

Answer (score 1):

As an addendum, my former French professor (Henri Godard) recently sent me an email to add another dimension to the current use of “songer”. He writes:

“On ne l’emploie guère à l’oral, tout au plus avec une légère dérision :  « À quoi tu songes? »”

I take this to mean something like, for example, what a Democrat might say after a friend displayed a “Make America Great Again” bumper sticker on his car. “À quoi tu songeais??” What were you *thinking*??