# Quelle est la différence entre « penser » et « songer » ?

Tags: choix-de-mot

Parfois je vois le mot «songer» être utilisé dans le même sens que «penser», mais la définition dans le dictionnaire n'est pas claire pour moi.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a distinction between "le rêve" and "le songe"?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/41333/is-there-a-distinction-between-le-r%c3%aave-and-le-songe)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Penser est le verbe passe-partout, avec une pléthore de significations très vaste : raisonner, concevoir, envisager, réfléchir etc. Il est employé le plus couramment.
Penser met en avant l'élément rationnel (je pense, donc je suis).

Songer est plutôt utilisé dans la locution 'songer à', dans le sens de projeter, avoir l'intention de, envisager, méditer; dans ce sens il est plus utilisé que 'penser à'.
Songer est plus vague signifiant aussi rêver.

Voir

https://dict.leo.org/forum/viewGeneraldiscussion.php?idForum=10&idThread=72975&lp=frde&lang=fr

https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/songer-penser.2666863/

**EDIT**

Voir la réponse complète de l'utilisateur @jlliagre ici : [Is there a distinction between "le rêve" and "le songe"?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/41333/is-there-a-distinction-between-le-r%c3%aave-and-le-songe)

Un extrait :

> The verb *songer*, while rare, is still used but has shifted its
> meaning from *rêver* to *penser* with a small nuance. *Penser* means
> to think (of something) while *songer* is more like to imagine the
> eventuality of something, to consider something. Compare:
>
> > *Je pense me présenter aux élections.* : Odds are high it will happen.
> >
> > *Je pense à me présenter aux élections.* : I do not forget to do it.
> >
> > *Je songe à me présenter aux élections.* : I'm still unsure and likely still weighing up the pros and cons.
>
> We can see that in the *songer* case, there is still a part of dream
> in the sense imaginary images or events are showing up in your mind.

Comment: "Je pense me présenter aux élections." : I have a good mind to do it / I have half a mind to stand for election. //"Je pense à me présenter aux élections.": I am considering standing for election.//"Je songe à me présenter aux élections.": I am considering standing for election.(true: I'm still unsure and likely still weighing up the pros and cons.)