# What's the difference between "je suis dans un rêve" and "je suis en songe"?

Tags: anglais

I wanted to translate the sentence "I am in a dream" in french. I've seen several translations. Google translate says it's "Je suis dans un rêve" but I know google translate can be off when it comes to grammar. I've also read that songe and rêve are the same but have slightly different meanings. I wanted the sentence to mean as someone finally accomplishing a dream and feeling like they are living in a dream. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Related: [Is there a distinction between "le rêve" and "le songe"?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/41333/is-there-a-distinction-between-le-r%c3%aave-and-le-songe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No matter  what is meant by "to be in a dream", whether it is "being a character in a real dream that was experienced" shortly before speaking (1), or  "being a character who is presently living in a dream-like fashion (figurative dream) and who is aware of this" (2), the two words are interchangeable; however,  "songe" is  literary and hardly used in everyday language; nevertheless, in books people can sometimes be made to express themselves in a literary fashion.

"Je suis dans un rêve" can be said if a proper context is found, but there is no common context. "Je suis en songe", or for that matter, "je suis en rêve" is not idiomatic at all.

(1) *literal* - You can use either ("Je suis dans un rêve/songe.").

- Je suis dans un rêve/songe. Ma personne a captivé l'intérêt d'une autre, je suis important(e)  pour quelqu'un et ça me redonne espoir en la vie. (*The dream is someone else's dream and he or she has been told by someone that they had dreamt of them, which made them feel proud; it is quite conceivable, for instance in the case of someone who has been shunned by their fellows for a long time; however this is by no means the only possibility, of course.*)
- Je pense parfois à quelque chose qui m'est arrivé il y a longtemps, que je n'ai jamais oublié bien que ce soit assez banal, et je me demande pourquoi c'est toujours très net dans ma mémoire ; je suis dans un rêve/songe; c'est un de mes rêves où je me vois flotter à travers l'espace à la rencontre de personnes de toutes sortes, mais que je  connais. (*This time the person speaking is the dreamer.*)

(2) *figurative* - Here again both can be used.

- La vie pour moi n'a rien de réel, n'a aucune consistance, tout n'est qu'inaccessible et sans substance ; je suis dans un rêve/songe, où mes émotions me controllent.

Answer (score 0):

The distinction between "songe" and "rêve" (answered [here](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/41333/is-there-a-distinction-between-le-r%C3%AAve-and-le-songe)) is discussed here.

Concerning your primary question as far as I understand, if you wnt to say that "what you are doing is something that you always dreamt of" you could say :

> Je vis mon rêve. C'est la vie dont j'ai toujours rêvé.

or

> Je suis dans un rêve.

you could also add "éveillé" to insist on the fact that the dream is "true".

> Je suis dans un rêve éveillé.

For stating that you achieved something (e.g. a gold medal for an athlete) it could be

> Mon rêve est accompli.